# Assembly reference issue in combination with com objects

Tags: .net, wpf, reference, com, .net-assembly

we have a WPF project, which uses third party librarys and a couple of internal packages. The wpf programm works fine on it's own, the assemblies get resolved correctly and the code works great.
The programm provides a possibilty to load data from different sources, depending on how you started it. As mentioned earlier, when called on it's own, it all works great, but if we call the programm from a different application, which is done by providing a controller and registering it as COM interop, we run into assembly reference issues.

```
[Guid("93BC7929-8A5F-43EA-AEAB-38B5034758E5")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ConnectionController : ControllerBase
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        var view = new MainWindow {DataContext = viewModel};
        view.Show();
    }
}
```

Because the wpf programm is also provided as a standalone application, **we moved the controller to a different project** which does not reference a lot of the assemblys, for example somekind of wpf library.

The controller himself does not hold anymore logic, usually it passes somekind of data which is provided by the com object, but all in all, the only thing it does is trying to instantiate the MainWindowViewModel in a different project. The projects which are in the same solution as the controller are resolved correctly, but the third party stuff is not.

As soon as we call the wpf programm by the controller, the project, which references the third party librarys, cannot resolve it's references anymore and throws an exception.

What is the correct way to solve this kind of issue? Do we have to register the third party dlls in the GAC? Or is their somekind of property we have to adjust? We can't get our heads around it. Every information about references and how they are resolved is appreciated.

Comment: "different application" is the problem.  The CLR still looks for assemblies the normal way, first the GAC and next the directory of the EXE file.  Even if that EXE is not a managed app.  Only the DLL that has the [ComVisible] types can be found automatically if you used /codebase when you registered it.  So the GAC solves it and copying the DLLs into the other app's install directory solves it.  Technically you might be able to make AppDomain.AssemblyResolve work but it is important that you have a God class that the client code always has to create first.

Comment: @Hans Passant thank you very much, that information solved our problem and led to more insight on that topic. Could you copy/paste your comment as answer? I would like to mark the question as answered

Comment: Just share the approach you used in your own post, I cannot guess what you decided to do.  Mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hans Passant, we found a solution for our problem. For the first try, we just copied the needed dlls into the folder of the executing assembly and it worked like a charm. This won't be the final solution, most likely we will use codebase, but it would also be possible to use the god class, because the controller will always be created first. I think we'll try to keep the controller as small as possible and are going to let the application handle how it gets it's ressources.